# jQuery resize() issues

Tags: jquery, substr, window-resize

I have a few functions inside of a resize function, and I am having trouble getting these functions to work as intended in some window resizing scenarios. For example, when the page loads with a window width > 1001 and you resize the window width < 500, the functions inside of the resize function no longer work properly. The functions that do not work are related to text display, bound to buttons.

I need help looking figuring out why these functions are not working properly.

Here is a fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/carbot3000/tuttjLp2/11/

In the fiddle you are going to need to resize the output container to understand what I'm talking about. Start out with a very large width, and then resize it to be < 500px (small).

Here are the functions -

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    jQuery(window).resize(function() {
         checkScreenSize();
    });

    checkScreenSize();

    function checkScreenSize() {
        var newWindowWidth = jQuery(window).width();

        if (newWindowWidth > 1001) {
            var showChar = 700; // How many characters are shown by default
            jQuery('.reviewbody').each(function() {
                 var rvwElem = jQuery(this);
                 var fullVal = rvwElem.html();
                 var truncatedVal = fullVal.substr(0, showChar);
                 console.log(fullVal);
                 console.log(fullVal.length);

                 if (fullVal.length > showChar) {
                    jQuery(rvwElem).parent(".mySlides").find('.btnMore').first().show().on('click', function() {
                        jQuery(this).html(jQuery(this).text() == 'View Less' ? 'View More' : 'View Less');
                        jQuery(".home_testimonial_section .home_testimonial_slider_wrap").toggleClass("rvwHeight");
                        jQuery(rvwElem).html(jQuery(rvwElem).html() == truncatedVal ? fullVal : truncatedVal);
                        console.log(fullVal);
                        console.log(fullVal.length);
                    });
                 }

                // You still want to show the content if it is shorter than "showChar"
                jQuery(rvwElem).html(truncatedVal);
                console.log(truncatedVal);
            });
        } else if (newWindowWidth < 500) {
            var showChar = 200; // How many characters are shown by default

            jQuery('.reviewbody').each(function() {
                var rvwElem = jQuery(this);
                var fullVal = rvwElem.html();
                var truncatedVal = fullVal.substr(0, showChar);
                console.log(fullVal);
                console.log(fullVal.length);

                if (fullVal.length > showChar) {
                    jQuery(rvwElem).parent(".mySlides").find('.btnMore').first().show().on('click', function() {
                        jQuery(this).html(jQuery(this).text() == 'View Less' ? 'View More' : 'View Less');
                        jQuery(".home_testimonial_section .home_testimonial_slider_wrap").toggleClass("rvwHeight");
                        jQuery(rvwElem).html(jQuery(rvwElem).html() == truncatedVal ? fullVal : truncatedVal);
                        console.log(fullVal);
                        console.log(fullVal.length);
                    });
                }

                // You still want to show the content if it is shorter than "showChar"
                jQuery(rvwElem).html(truncatedVal);
                console.log(truncatedVal);
            }); 

 }
  }
});
```

Comment: As far as I can tell you lack at least three of these bad boys, `}`, at the end of your code

Comment: Those bad boys are in the fiddle, but I didn't include them by accident in the code snippet. I'll add them now.